# Xpath to find the webelement inside div tag

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing, xpath, automated-tests

I want to assert a client name which is present inside the div tags.

Below is the HTML code.

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 dl-no-margin-bottom">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 dl-no-margin-bottom">
                <label class="dl-padding-top-5">Client Name:</label>
                <br>
                <label class="dl-font-robotolight dl-font-14" id="clientName1eb0d7867">MOLOANTOA MOTAUNG</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 dl-no-margin-bottom">
                <label class="dl-padding-top-5">Client Name at Bureau:</label>
                <br>
                <label class="dl-font-robotolight dl-font-14" id="clientName2eb0d7867">MOLOANTOA MOTAUNG</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i want to assert the names of the ID:clientName1eb0d7867 & clientName2eb0d7867.But i am unable to locate the element with below code were i am getting unable to locate element error.

```
String actual_clientname = driver.FindElement(By.Id("clientName1cb737f0d")).Text;
            String expected_clientname = "MOLOANTOA MOTAUNG";
            Assert.AreEqual(actual_clientname, expected_clientname);
            Console.WriteLine("Client Name validated successfully");
            String actual_Bureauname = driver.FindElement(By.Id("clientName2cb737f0d")).Text;
            String expected_Bureauname = "MOLOANTOA MOTAUNG";
            Assert.AreEqual(actual_Bureauname, expected_Bureauname);
            Console.WriteLine("Client Name validated successfully");
```

Also tried,

```
//*[@class='dl-font-robotolight dl-font-14'][@id='clientName1cb737f0d']"));
```

But getting the same error.

what is the right way to do it?
kindly suggest.

Comment: `//label[@id='clientName1eb0d7867']` should work. You cannot combine two attributes like that, and should use `[@attr1='val1' and @attr2='val2']

Comment: @OguzOzgul Thanks for your reply.But i am still getting the same error.

Comment: Message: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//label[@id='clientName1eb0d7867']"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.92)

Comment: Are you sure the download is completed successfully? Can you save the document to your disk and see? (driver.PageSource ?)

Comment: Look for any parent `iframe` higher up in the html source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I see a value like "clientName1cb737f0d" this is usually dynamically driven each time with the alphanumeric value of "1cb737f0d"?

If so, can you try something like this?

```
var name = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//label[text()='Client Name:']/following-sibling::label")).Text;

var bureau = var bureau = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[text()='Client Name at Bureau:']/following-sibling::label")).Text;
```